# How to scrape the website investing to get every technical analysis for a stock

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize, watir

I am trying to scrape the website https://investing.com/ to get technical data for any stocks. I would like to get for "Moving Averages:" & "Technical Indicators:" how many buys and how many sells with different periods :

- 5 hours
- Daily
- Weekly

Here is an image to see data I want to get :
https://i.ibb.co/mHpM0Yw/Capture-d-e-cran-2019-08-14-a-00-15-45.png

the url is https://investing.com/equities/credit-agricole-technical

When you navigate to the browser, the period is set to "hourly" and you have to click an another period to get the correct data. The DOM is update after an XML request.

I would like to scrape the page after DOM updated.

### Mechanize

I have try to scrape with Mechanize and click on "weekly" and get the DOM to scrape it but i got an error

here is my code :

```
    def mechanize_scraper(url)
      agent = Mechanize.new
      puts agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
      page = agent.get(url)
      link = page.link_with(text: 'Weekly')
      new_page = link.click
    end


    url = "https://investing.com/equities/credit-agricole-technical"
    mechanize_scraper(url)
```

here is the error :

> Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError (Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError)

When we inspect the DOM, the  link has an its attributes "href" = javascript(void);

```
    <li pairid="407" data-period="week" class="">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">Weekly</a>
    </li>
```

So after some tries and lots of google search, I move on "Watir" to try to scrape.

### Watir

here is my code :

```
    def watir_scraper(url)
      Watir.default_timeout = 10
      browser = Watir::Browser.new
      browser.goto(url)       
      link = browser.link(text: /weekly/).click
      pp link
    end

    url = "https://investing.com/equities/credit-agricole-technical"
    watir_scraper(url)
```

here is the error :

> 40: from app.rb:47:in `'

> 39: from app.rb:32:in `watir_scraper'

> 38: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:145:in `click'

> 37: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:789:in `element_call'

> 36: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:154:in `block in click'

> 35: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:74:in `click'

> 34: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:371:in `click_element'

> 33: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:567:in `execute'

> 32: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'

> 31: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:64:in `call'

> 30: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:114:in `request'

> 29: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:88:in `create_response'

> 28: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:88:in `new'

> 27: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'

> 26: from /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:72:in `assert_ok'

> 25: from 25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5aaa440d thread_start + 13

> 24: from 24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5aaa8249 _pthread_start + 66

> 23: from 23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5aaa52eb _pthread_body + 126

> 22: from 22  chromedriver                        0x000000010b434e67 chromedriver + 3673703

> 21: from 21  chromedriver                        0x000000010b416014 chromedriver + 3547156

> 20: from 20  chromedriver                        0x000000010b3e0f07 chromedriver + 3329799

> 19: from 19  chromedriver                        0x000000010b3f91b8 chromedriver + 3428792

> 18: from 18  chromedriver                        0x000000010b3cd069 chromedriver + 3248233

> 17: from 17  chromedriver                        0x000000010b3f86d8 chromedriver + 3426008

> 16: from 16  chromedriver                        0x000000010b3f8940 chromedriver + 3426624

> 15: from 15  chromedriver                        0x000000010b3ecc1f chromedriver + 3378207

> 14: from 14  chromedriver                        0x000000010b0ce8a5 chromedriver + 108709

> 13: from 13  chromedriver                        0x000000010b0cd7e2 chromedriver + 104418

> 12: from 12  chromedriver                        0x000000010b0f1bf3 chromedriver + 252915

> 11: from 11  chromedriver                        0x000000010b0fba37 chromedriver + 293431

> 10: from 10  chromedriver                        0x000000010b0f1c4e chromedriver + 253006

> 9: from 9   chromedriver                        0x000000010b0cfa66 chromedriver + 113254

> 8: from 8   chromedriver                        0x000000010b0f1a72 chromedriver + 252530

> 7: from 7   chromedriver                        0x000000010b0cfe66 chromedriver + 114278

> 6: from 6   chromedriver                        0x000000010b0d63fb chromedriver + 140283

> 5: from 5   chromedriver                        0x000000010b0d71a9 chromedriver + 143785

> 4: from 4   chromedriver                        0x000000010b0d8d19 chromedriver + 150809

> 3: from 3   chromedriver                        0x000000010b0da569 chromedriver + 157033

> 2: from 2   chromedriver                        0x000000010b15fcef chromedriver + 703727

> 1: from 1   chromedriver                        0x000000010b3bf133 chromedriver + 3191091
> 0x000000010b42f129 chromedriver + 3649833: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (544, 704). Other element would receive the click: ... (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)
> (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

I hope everything can help you to understand my issue. I would like to know if I can scrape datas with Mechanize or Watir. If not, which tools can do the job ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's exactly what you're looking for, but it may get you a little closer.

Using an HTTP sniffer, found that the link you're trying to click makes a POST.  The response of that POST can be obtained with:

```
def mechanize_poster(url)
  agent = Mechanize.new
  headers = {
    'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent' => 'Mac Safari',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Referer' => 'https://www.investing.com/equities/credit-agricole-technical'
  }
  fields = {
    period: 'week',
    viewType: 'normal',
    pairID: '407'
  }
  page = agent.post(url, fields, headers)
  p page
end
```

I think you'll need to use some Nokogiri to get at the data values.

Comment: Thanks ! I work well. I just want to get sell & buy numbers for each period to decide if it is a good opportunity to buy/sell it and estimates how many times to keep the stock.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just with requests and bs4 using POST. Same idea as in other answer I see but use a loop to provide for all values requested. I simply used dev tools to monitor web traffic when clicking 5hr, Daily etc then observed the xhr calls.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Referer': 'https://www.investing.com/equities/credit-agricole-technical',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

body = {'pairID' : 407, 'period': '', 'viewType' : 'normal'}
periods = {'5hr': 18000, 'Daily': 86400, 'Weekly': 'week'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for k, v in periods.items():
        body['period'] = v
        r = s.post('https://www.investing.com/instruments/Service/GetTechincalData', data = body, headers = headers)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        for i in soup.select('#techStudiesInnerWrap .summaryTableLine'):
            print(k, ' : ' , ' '.join([j.text for j in i.select('span')]))
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I saw your post.
is it possible for you to check my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75375722/how-can-i-webscrape-the-website-investing-com-who-receives-data-from-an-external/75376714#75376714

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing in Watir is coming from webdriver and indicates that if a human tried to click that link, some other element on the page would get clicked instead (because that other element overlaps the link.

Likely the default browser size is small and you are dealing with a 'reactive' design that doesn't scale down well below a given size (common issue)

Try setting the screen size first, to be similar to what you would be using (e.g. 1024x768 or larger) `@browser.window.resize_to(1920, 1080)`