# How can i webscrape the website investing.com who receives data from an external API?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

i am trying to webscrape the following website: https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/.

Through research, i know there are 2 methods to scrape this website:

1. requests
2. selenium

This website receives data from an external api:
https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData

With request, the websites send additional information about the api-call for example if I want the economic data from january 1st till january 2nd, the website will send these 2 dates with the payload.

I tried to make an api call to the link but i got an error code 403, after researching i found out that my headers were incorrect, but i don´t know how to fix this.

Can you maybe explain me how to webscrape this website?

I have the feeling that this website is protected by cloudfare or something like that.
Below my code.

```
import json
import datetime
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def Get_calendar_data():
    headers = {
    'authority': 'www.investing.com',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path':'/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': '*/*',
    #'accept-encoding': 'gzip', 'deflate', 'br',
     #'accept-language': ('nl-NL','nl;q=0.9','en-US;q=0.8','en;q=0.7'),
     'content-length': '439',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin': 'https://www.investing.com',
    'Referer':'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/',
    #'sec-ch-ua': ("Not_A Brand;v=99", "Google Chrome;v=109", "Chromium;v=109"),
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode':'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site':'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }

    url = 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData'

    body = {
        'dateFrom': '2023-02-07',
        'dateTo': '2023-02-08'
    }
    with requests.session() as r:

        s = r.post(url, data = body, headers = headers)
        print(s)


Get_calendar_data()

fetch("https://www.investing.com/economic-

calendar/Service/getCalendarFilteredData", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not_A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"109\", \"Chromium\";v=\"109\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
  },
  "referrer": "https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "country%5B%5D=25&country%5B%5D=32&country%5B%5D=6&country%5B%5D=37&country%5B%5D=72&country%5B%5D=22&country%5B%5D=17&country%5B%5D=39&country%5B%5D=14&country%5B%5D=10&country%5B%5D=35&country%5B%5D=43&country%5B%5D=56&country%5B%5D=36&country%5B%5D=110&country%5B%5D=11&country%5B%5D=26&country%5B%5D=12&country%5B%5D=4&country%5B%5D=5&dateFrom=2023-03-01&dateTo=2023-03-09&timeZone=8&timeFilter=timeRemain&currentTab=custom&limit_from=0",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
}); ;
```

Comment: `HTTP error 403` means server unable to authorized it. It is required `auth`  token to access the API endpoint. you might to sign in and then get the token or cookie to use in the header.

Comment: I see a token in my local storage but i don't know how to add the auth token.

Comment: Use that code. `headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + authToken}`